# variable as document index

Tags: c++, dom, enums

I am using the rapidjson library to parse json data.

To read an element I use, for example, this code:

```
Document d;
d.Parse(json); //Parse JSON data
d["name"].Accept(writer)
```

Which sends this to a StringBuffer which allows me to read the data as a String. But now I'm trying to make this reading dynamic. Now I read the field "name" but this can differ. So I'd like to do this with a variable and I tried this:

```
String s = "name";
d[s].Accept(writer)
```

But this results in the error

> Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the type of `d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what actually happens when you call `d["name"]` cause of c++ operator overloading, but "name" is basically a `const char*` not a String.

So I would assume that

```
const char* s = "name";
d[s].Accept(writer);
```

would work much better.

Actually the in c++ the standard operator [] is defined to take a std::size_t. String cannot be casted into a std::size_t, but any pointer, such as `const char*` can. That is meant by "integral or unscoped enum".

But for map types the [] operator can take non-integral values, such as complex objects, or whatever. But it seems that your operator [] behaves like the standard array subscript.

BTW: In rapidjson (I just checked the github source) a GenericDocument is a GenericValue that has the operator

```
GenericValue& operator[](const std::basic_string<Ch>& name) { return (*this)[GenericValue(StringRef(name))]; }
```

So you might be able to use a `std::string`.

Answer (score -1):

It is quite hard to answer the question when we don't know the type of your variables. I'll assume `d` is solve kind of collection containing some kind of objects of the type `MyClass` with a Accept function.

If you want such behavior, you must use something like an std map.

It is used like this:

```
// The key type is string and the value type is myClass
//  key     value
map<string, MyClass> myDict;

myDict["name"].Accept(writer);
```

Now you can have a string associated with a MyClass.

Btw, a `string` starts with a lower case. The compiler won't find `String`.

EDIT:
Ah! The type of `d` is a json document! If you want to manipulate json documents like this, you must use an external library such as [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

EDIT:
Seems you already use a json library.

Comment: Why the -1? Any explanation? Any suggestion to improve this answer? Is there something I missed?